# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdownList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to output data from an object, but I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdownList' of undefined", before the Lesson array all objects arrive successfully, but then undefined appears, what could be the problem? everything else jsx removed for readability
https://ibb.co/hRytjMB
https://ibb.co/6F1YcBr

**Lesson.jsx**

```
{
    this.props.lesson.dropdown.dropdownList.map(option =>
        items.push(<option>{option.par}</option>)
    )
}
```

**lesson-reducer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {faDotCircle} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faDotCircle";

const ADD_LESSON = "ADD_LESSON";
const one = "Robby";

let initialState = {
    lessonsTitle: [
        {
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: [
                <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
                ` advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.`
            ],
            dropdown: {
                titleName: "JSON",
                dropdownList: {
                    par: 'Hello World',
                }
            }

        },
        {
            titleName: "Boolean",
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: `
                Folly words widow one downs few age every seven. tolerably.
            `,
            languages: [
                'Язык HTML2',
            ]
        },
        {
            titleName: "Math",
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: `
               Another journey chamber way yet females man.
            `,
            languages: [
                'Язык HTML3',
            ]
        },
    ],

};
```

Comment: `this.props.lesson` is an array with three elements. Check your first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an incoherent structure in your reducer, causing the undefined error. For the the first object it should work because you do have a dropdown object, but the other two don't which may cause the issue.

Additionaly your dropdownList is an object when it seems it should be an array if you want to iterate over it.

you could try this verification to keep it clean:

```
this.props.dropdown?.dropdownList?.map(...)
```

The interrogation point there checks if the preceding value is null or undefined and if its not it provides access to its properties. Otherwise it skips whatever is in front and to the next code statement.

Also you should iterate lessons as it is an array

Comment: Gentlemens, before I asked the question, I tried these options that you listed, I made a dropdown array, deleted the last two objects, but all to no avail

Comment: Could you post a pastebin with the code with the suggestions? Maybe we could be move forward from there. The way it is now it wont work for sure and its harder to debug

Answer (score 0):

the reason you get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dropdownList' of undefined`
is because you are trying to access `this.props.lesson` without an index, and its an array/

since `this.props.lesson` is an array, i think you want to use `map()` over `this.props.lesson` to achieve your goal